# Did Donnie Yen beat up eight men in one fight?

Tags: martial-arts

According to Wikipedia, Donnie Yen one [beat up eight men guys in a single fight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donnie_Yen#Real_fighting_experience_and_prowess):

> There's one reported occasion that confirms him being an efficient
>   martial artist. According to news reports by Hong Kong news channels
>   in the late 1990s, Yen was at a nightclub with his then girlfriend,
>   Joey Meng. Inside the nightclub, Joey got harassed by a troublesome
>   gang who had taken an interest in her. Yen warned them to leave her
>   alone but to no avail. As Yen and Joey left the club, the gang
>   followed and attacked Yen. According to the news, Yen beat up eight
>   members of the gang who were hospitalized.

The source is in Chinese so I don't know what says or how reputable it is. I've seen Donnie Yen movies where he's tackled multiple people at once in stage-combat, but surely it doesn't go down quite the same way in real life. I imagine it'd be almost impossible to defend from more than a couple of guys.

Is there any evidence this actually happened?

Comment: There's a video of a Russian boxer putting down two guys with two punches: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U-uztmpj4Mc.  Multiple opponents aren't necessarily a problem...

Comment: I've heard that unless the others are organized, after a certain point, they start getting in each other's way. It would be difficult for 8 randoms to effectively attack a single person.